# Is it possible to use component (like jButton) as an argument in a function?

Tags: java, netbeans, jbutton

If I am using the exact same lines of code for multiple buttons, can I use a component (in this case button) as an argument for a function instead of using a variable? That will make my work so much easier. If I have something like this:

```
a1.setText("something");
a1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
a1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

a2.setText("something");
a2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
a2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

a3.setText("something");
a3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
a3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

Can I make them into one function something like:

```
public void buttonFunction(Button something){
    something.setText("something");
    something.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    something.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

If I can, how can I?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Just call it like a regular function.  Careful that Swing is not thread safe; this must be done on the EDT.

Comment: Re, "Can I make them into one function...?"  What happened when you _tried_ it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is.
The attempt you made is the way to do this.

```
public void buttonFunction(JButton something){
    something.setText("something");
    something.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    something.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

All you need to do is call this function after you created the JButton objects.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that can work. 
You can pass anything as a parameter even methods, classes and types.

**1.** Here is a simple method that can do what you asked:

```
public static Component setUpComponent(Component component){
    if(component instanceof JButton){
        JButton button = (JButton)component;
        button.setText("something");
        button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        return button;
    } else if(component instanceof <"Some other class, like JPanel">){
       //do something else for that class
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid Object");
    return null;
}
```

Here is how you can use this:

```
for(int index = 0; index <= 2; index++){
    JButton button = new JButton();
    setUpComponent(button);
    //do whatever you want to do
}
```

**2.** You could also create a method that simply gives you a ready Button:

```
public static JButton getButton(){
    JButton button = new JButton("something");
    button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    return button;
}
```

Here is how you can use this:

```
for(int index = 0; index <= 2; index++){
    JButton button = setUpComponent(button);
    //do whatever you want to do
}
```

**3.** But in my opinion the best way to go about this is to create a new Class and setup the buttons there. Like so:

```
public class CustomButton extends JButton{

    public CustomButton(){
        this("something",Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE);
    }

    public CustomButton(String text, Color backColor, Color frontColor){
        super(something);
        setBackground(backColor);
        setForeground(frontColor);
    }

}
```

Here is how you can use this:

```
for(int index = 0; index <= 2; index++){
    JButton button = new CustomButton();
    //same as:
    //CustomButton button = new CustomButton();
    //or
    //JButton button = new CustomButton("something",Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE);
}
```